# .htaccess move up one directory level issue

Tags: .htaccess

i was unable to find answer, so there it is:

i need to get URL like this:   //mydomain/index.php?var=username (or https:// if user want secure connection).

To use nice URL I want to use:  //mydomain/user/username (this should stay in the browser URL line) to get: //mydomain/index.php?var=username

I have configured .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?var=$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work. When i use redirection [R,L] it works fine, but in the URL line of browser is the ugly URL after it :(

Please can You help me, what i have wrong?

Comment: It looks okay.  When you say it doesn't work, what actually happens instead?  404? 500?

Comment: It doesn't return error, it shows the page, but it seems, that the URL is something like this: //mydomain/user/ instead od //mydomain/ so all links (including relative paths are directed to //mydomain/user/... instead of //mydomain/...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment

> It doesn't return error, it shows the page, but it seems, that the URL is something like this: //mydomain/user/
>   instead od //mydomain/ so all links (including relative paths are
>   directed to //mydomain/user/... instead of //mydomain/...)

Describes normal (expected) behaviour.  Your browser thinks the page is being served from //mydomain/user/userid so all relative links will be resolved using the base path //mydomain/user/.  What's more, your htaccess rule allows an optional trailing slash so //mydomain/user/userid/ is also valid.  A request like that will resolve all links relative to //mydomain/user/userid/, so an href of "foo.html" will point to //mydomain/user/userid/foo.html.

The only real solution here is to make all your links relative to the root folder by adding a "/" at the start.  For instance, instead of things like:

```
<a href="foo.html">
<img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<form action="processme.php" method="post">
```

You should use

```
<a href="/foo.html">
<img src="/images/pic.jpg" alt="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />
<form action="/processme.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank You. There is another issue, afterwards, but it is a question for my PHP script, so it should be done. Thank You.